# Prove the Trigonometric Identity: $\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing some math exercises but I got stuck on this problem.

In the book of Bogoslavov Vene it says to prove that:

$$\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}.$$

It is easy if we do it like this: $\sin^2 x = (1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)=1-\cos^2 x$.
But how to prove it just by going from the left part or from the right

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: $$\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac{\sin x(1+\cos x)}{1-\cos^2 x}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we must have that $\cos x \neq 1$, so x cannot be any even multiple of $\pi$. Similarly, $\sin x \neq 0$, so x cannot be any multiple of $\pi$.

Why do I note the above?

Because we have an identity, $$\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$ which is senseless if $\cos x = 1,$ and/or $\sin x = 0$.

$\require{cancel}$
Since $x$ cannot be any multiple of $\pi$, we can multiply numerator and denominator by $1+ \cos x$, because we already ruled out $x$ = integer multiple of $\pi$.

We also use the Pythagorean Identity $$\sin^2x + \cos^2 x =1 \iff 1 - \cos^2 x = \sin^2 x$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)}{(1-\cos(x))}&= \frac{\sin(x)}{(1-\cos(x))}\cdot \frac{(1+\cos(x))}{(1+\cos(x))} \\ \\ & = \frac{\sin x(1 + \cos x)}{\underbrace{1- \cos^2 x}_{(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2}} \\ \\
& = \frac {\sin x(1 + \cos x)}{\sin^2 x} \\ \\
& = \frac{\cancel{\sin x}(1 + \cos x)}{\cancel{\sin x}\cdot \sin x} \\ \\
& = \frac{1 +\cos x}{\sin x}\end{align}$$

for all $x \neq k\pi, k\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Nice illustrated! +1

Comment: As long as $\cos x \ne -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(x)}{(1-\cos(x))}&= \frac{\sin(x)}{(1-\cos(x))} \times \frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\iff  \sin^2x=1-\cos^2x=(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)$$

$$\implies \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$