# An alternative form for $\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry

> $\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=$(choose one option from the followings)
>
> a) $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$
>
> b) $\frac{\cos x-1}{\sin x}$
>
> c) $\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}$
>
> d) $\frac{\sin x+1}{\cos x}$

From the options, I can see that answer should be c) as by cross-multiplication, we get an identity.

But I am unable to solve it if I don't play with the options.

I wish somebody could help. I am looking for a step-wise-solution approach, staring from the problem and reaching the solution, and not involving the options in the process.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510016/prove-trigonometric-identity-frac-sin-x1-cos-x-frac1-cos-x-sin-x

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144). Also, note the changes I made to your maths expressions, which make them look nicer.

Comment: For this kind of problem, you do need to know options because there are so many more expressions that are equal to the original expression.

Comment: @Lord_Farin- Points noted for future. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}.$$