# Proving a trigonometric identity: $\frac{2\sin^{3}x}{1-\cos x} = 2\sin x + \sin 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I really need some help with this question. I need to prove this identity:
$$\frac{2\sin^{3}x}{1-\cos x} = 2\sin x + \sin 2x.$$

Comment: Thank you Ian Mateus for fixing my equation. I will try to figure out how to do that. I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: For future reference, there is a quick tutorial about how I did it [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\frac{2\sin^3x}{1-\cos x}=2\sin^2x\cdot\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}=2\sin^2x\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$(using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510016/prove-trigonometric-identity-frac-sin-x1-cos-x-frac1-cos-x-sin-x/510025#510025))

$\displaystyle=2\sin x(1+\cos x)=2\sin x+2\sin x\cos x=\cdots$

Comment: and sin2x=2sinxcosx I believe that double angle identity

Comment: I understand it now. THANK YOU SO MUCH!! :)

Comment: @Paula, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html. Nice to hear that

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$\sin^3(x) = \sin(x) \sin^2(x) = \sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x)) = \sin(x)(1+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x))$$
and finally make use of $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x) \cos(x)$ to get what you want.