# Solve identity: $\frac {\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac {1+\cos x}{\sin x}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac {\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac {1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$
The only way I can see of doing this is by cross multiplying but isn't that not allowed when trying to prove something?

Comment: See also: [Prove Trigonometric Identity $\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/510016). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%20%7B%5Csin%20x%7D%7B1-%5Ccos%20x%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%20%7B1%2B%5Ccos%20x%7D%7B%5Csin%20x%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3):

Note that the identity doesn't work for some values of $x$, specifically when $\sin(x) = 0$ or when $1 - \cos(x) = 0$. However, if $1 - \cos(x) = 0$, then

\begin{align*}
& \cos(x) = 1 \\
\implies& \cos^2(x) = 1 \\
\implies& \sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x) = 0 \\
\implies& \sin(x) = 0,
\end{align*}

so really the identity only fails if $\sin(x) = 0$.

Otherwise, let's suppose $\sin(x) \neq 0$. By the above argument, then $1 - \cos(x) \neq 0$. We start with the known identity,
$$\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x).$$
Then, using difference of two squares,
$$\sin^2(x) = (1 - \cos(x))(1 + \cos(x)).$$
Since $\sin(x) \neq 0$, we may divide both sides by it:
$$\sin(x) = \frac{(1 - \cos(x))(1 + \cos(x))}{\sin(x)}.$$
Since $1 - \cos(x) \neq 0$, we may also divide by it:
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{1 - \cos(x)} = \frac{1 + \cos(x)}{\sin(x)}.$$

---

Note that I've essentially used cross multiplication, but in reverse. I've started with $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$, the result that we obtain by cross multiplying the above expression. I've then carefully undone the process of cross multiplying, to obtain the equality we wanted to prove.

Why do I write it out this way? Because it's technically a fallacy to start by manipulating the expression you want to prove, obtain something known to be true, and therefore conclude the original expression is true. It's an example of [the fallacy of affirming the consequent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent)

A more blatant example is the following: Suppose $-1 = 1$. Then squaring both sides yields $(-1)^2 = 1^2$, which implies $1 = 1$, which is true. Thus, $-1 = 1$ (but not really).

In our example, there are similar, but lesser problems. Note that the identity we wanted to prove didn't work for all $x$, but cross-multiplying gave us an expression that did work for all $x$. It's not clear, when using cross multiplying (when forming the argument backwards) why there were any problems in the original expression. It's only when you start from $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$ and start dividing, that you run into issues with potentially dividing by $0$.

That might be why you've got it in your head that you're not allowed to cross-multiply. The thing is, cross-multiplying is a perfectly valid thing to do in a proof, but the more important thing is to always start with something you **know** to be true (e.g. $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$) and work your way to the conclusion that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cross-multiplying is perfectly allowed.

You start with $$\frac {\sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac {1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$

$$\iff \sin² x = (1- \cos x)(1+ \cos x) = 1 - \cos² x, \sin x \neq 0, \cos x  \neq 1$$

and the last expression is always true, such that the expression you started with is always true (in particular, we use the $\Leftarrow$ implication)

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$$ or
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1.$$

Also, we have:
$$\frac {\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1+\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$$

Comment: which, @RiktasMath, is true for all (real, at least) $x$

Comment: Oh, so cross multiplication is allowed if I know the answer is 100% true?

Comment: @RiktasMath In math there is no the  "cross multiplication" otherwise, there is something in the Lie's algebra. We can use a multiplication of the both sides by the common denominator. In our case it's $(1-\cos{x})\sin{x}$ and it works of course.

Comment: what do you think about $x\in \{k\pi\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}\cup\{2k\pi\mid k\in \mathbb Z\}$

Comment: @user380364 In these trigonometric problems we make all manipulations on the domain of the both sides.

Comment: Actually we do not. Rather, "we" study carefully said domains instead of hiding them under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

Set $t=\tan \frac x2$ so that $\sin x = \cfrac {2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos x = \cfrac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ (Weierstrass substitution) or $$(1+t^2)\sin x =2t; (1+t^2)\cos x=1-t^2$$

Since $1+t^2\ge 1 \gt 0$ we can multiply the original fractions by $1=\cfrac {1+t^2}{1+t^2}$ to obtain $$\frac {\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac {2t}{2t^2}=\frac 2{2t}=\frac {1+t^2+1-t^2}{2t}=\frac {1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$

The only issue is cancelling a factor of $\frac tt$ which is undefined when $t=0$, but then one of the original fractions reduces to $\frac 00$.

Comment: "Set t=tan(x/2)" Hmmm... No thanks.

Comment: @did You are probably right and I notice that I missed the case of $t$ infinite as a potential issue ($\sin x =0, \cos x =-1$). But it is sometimes convenient to work with rational functions rather than trigonometric ones, and the denominator $1+t^2$ is never zero.